# How to enable PIP on Android with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I'm using react-native-video to show videos for both iOS and Android with React native .64, but I can't seem to find anywhere that would allow me to do PIP like the prop in react-native-video. There was a PR that seemed to address it, but it was closed, and there isn't much online that shows how to do it. Does anybody know of a package or setting to get PIP mode working for Android?

Comment: Have you checked out this npm package: [react-native-pip-android](https://github.com/adkaushik/react-native-pip-android/blob/master/README.md)?